# C# Excel 2007 Error

Tags: c#, .net, excel, gridview

I have a simple code like this. This code simply exporting gridwiev to excel file..

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=cat5.xls");
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");
//Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7;
Response.Charset = "windows-1254";
//Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
Response.End();
```

But our company some users usign Excel 2003, some user using Excel 2007. When i run this code, there is no problem Excel 2003. But there is some problem in Excel 2007 like this pictures.

[image]
[image]

How can i solve this problem? Is there anybody have an idea?

Best Regards,
Soner.

Comment: Does this happen for all gridsizes? I had problems exporting to Excel from some library that got "solved" by appending some empty rows to get the filesize above (I think) 7k.

Comment: I don't calculate any filesize of gridsize or what? Just writing this code and run it. MY question is what is the different excel 2003 and excel 2007..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is by design (in Excel 2007): see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx

Possible work-around can be generating either csv file on server (but you will loose formatting) or generating actual excel file (using excel automation or 3rd party tool).

Comment: I too have encountered this before and I specified a .xlsx extension and all was well. Fortunately I could rely on the fact we were all using Office 2007, but that's a bit more tricky here.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove this line:

Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");

Then Cell data too large will be fixed.